# Google Script Delete Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey I'm trying to write a google script that will delete rows based on a True / False statement. I'm using the check marks, and have it delete the row. Also is there a way to have this run continuously or do I manually have to run this each time?

I can't seem to get the code run to delete the rows with a checkmark

```
function deleteRow()  {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  var editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EDIT");
  
  var lastRowEdit = editSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for(var i = 4; i <= lastRowEdit; i++)
  {
    
    if(editSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue() == 'TRUE')
    {
      editSheet.deleteRow(i);
      
  
}

  }
  
  
}
```

[Google Sheet Template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZE56VvxOskmAPi7Ubiv2OnL31XZN2WRyXoAsFAEuw7c/edit#gid=0)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `function deleteRow()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EDIT");
  var lastRowEdit = editSheet.getLastRow();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=4;i<=lastRowEdit;i++) {
    if(editSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue() == 'TRUE') {
      editSheet.deleteRow(i-d++);
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation / Issues:

- If your sheet column contains `TRUE/FALSE` values, these are returned as javascript boolean values in Google Apps Script. Therefore, the comparison you need to make is `getRange(i,4).getValue() == true` instead of `getRange(i,4).getValue() == 'TRUE'`.
- It is very inefficient to call `getRange` and `getValue` within a `for` loop. If you have many data this can quickly reach the quota.
- The proper solution is to get the data in column `D`. I see you want to start from the 4th cell, therefore `editSheet.getRange('D4:D'+ editSheet.getLastRow())`. But this will be a 2D array. You are interested in an particular column. Therefore it is more natural to have a 1D array. This is why you can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten it.
- Now that you have stored your data, you want to delete rows. But every time you delete a row, the structure of the sheet changes and therefore it won't map your original data. This is why you need to iterate **backwards**. I use a `forEach` loop here to make my code more clear and therefore I can [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) my dataset so I iterate every element from the end.
- Since `coldD` contains javascript boolean values. I can directly use `if(r)`.

### Solution:

```
function deleteRow(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EDIT");
  const colD = editSheet.getRange('D4:D'+ editSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();  
  colD.reverse().forEach((r,i)=>{
     if(r){ 
      editSheet.deleteRow(colD.length-i+3);
  }});
 
}
```

Comment: There will be more data entered in this sheet, so it just need to scan the D column for all the true or false statements. Does this work continuously or do I have to run the script each time for it take effect? Also can other Editors make changes to the sheet and the script will run?